# Hyper-V doesn't recognize wireless adapter

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 host with the same OS as a guest with Hyper-V. When I edit the settings and try to add an external adapter, only the physical network card is available. But in device manager for the host it obviously recognizes my USB network adapter. I've even enabled the Virtual Protocol for that adapter.

What do I need to do to get Hyper-V to recognize my wireless network card?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bad news:** You can not bind a wireless adapter to a virtual machine in Hyper-V.

*sad face*

There is, however, one workaround that you can use. Create a new virtual network (internal) and then use internet connection sharing to share your wireless adapter and then choose the internal virtual switch to share it with.

Comment: Can you spell this out a little bit more?